# Replace % followed by a number in a string

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, python-3.x, formatting

I am working on a class assignment which requires me to replace % followed by a number to its corresponding positional parameter (if any,assuming only such numbers and required parameters are given).I have been trying to solve this for hours to no avail.Searched Stack Overflow and web but the questions asked previously only replace the integer with something which is easy enough.

Ex:
formatting("Exodus  %0" , "Moses") -->should return "Exodus Moses"

formatting("Exodus %0 and %1", "Kings","Gods") --> should return "Exodus Kings and Gods"

formatting("Exodus %1 and %0", "Kings","Gods") --> should return "Exodus Gods and Kings"

By the looks  of it i think the function formatting prototype would be

```
def formatting(inputstring, *args):
```

Things i have tried so far

1.for loop to naively replace %number with its corresponding argument

```
for length in len(args):
    temp=temp.replace("%length","arg[length]")
```

Of course this wouldnt work because they are strings and not integers

2.Using inputstring.format() to return the required string.
  Problems are caused by varying args length
Ex:

```
if len(args) == 1:    
    return inputstring.replace("%0",args[0])
if len(args) == 2:
    inputstring = inputstring.replace("%0",args[0])
    return inputstring.replace("%1",args[1])
```

easy enough it works ! but doesnt feel right,cumbersome for many arguments
  tried doing this in a loop didnt work out

Please help
Thanks !

Comment: Surely Python has print statements that already do this kind of thing automatically.  Check here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: Consider `enumerate(args)`...

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Probably, but this is an assignment, I'm guessing they want the students to do it manually

Comment: @RobertHarvey :The closest i could find on that page was str.format() which intrinsically wants embedded string of form {number} and not %number , though i could be wrong i have to explore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it here:

```
for length in xrange(len(args)):
    temp = temp.replace("%length","arg[length]")
```

Consider:

```
>>> s = "Hello %length there %0 man"
>>> length = 0
>>> args = ["something"]
```

If you do the replacement you did, the wrong thing happens:

```
>>> s.replace("%length", "args[length]")
'Hello args[length] there %0 man'
```

You want to end up doing this:

```
>>> s.replace("%0", "something")
'Hello %length there something man'
```

How to do that? For a given index, you have to construct the string `"%"` followed by the index, and then get that value out of `args`:

```
>>> i = 0
>>> "%" + str(i)
'%0'
>>> args[i]
'something'    
>>> s.replace("%" + str(i), args[i])
'Hello %length there something man'
```

So your loop has to look like this:

```
>>> for i in xrange(len(args)):
        temp = temp.replace("%" + str(i), args[i])
```

Or, more pythonically, you can use `enumerate`, which lets you iterate through a list and get the indices at the same time:

```
>>> for i, arg in enumerate(args):
        temp = temp.replace("%" + str(i), arg)
```

Comment: use `enumerate` instead of looping over an index: `for idx, val in enumerate(args): temp = temp.replace("%{0}".format(idx), val)`

Comment: This will have issues if the number of args exceeds 9 though.

Comment: @Daniel: I realize, but I'm keeping it at a beginner level. I suppose I could add an "advanced" section..

Comment: @Claudiu : Ah perfect you nailed it ! Thank you this was driving me nuts . Any thoughts on if the argument count is greater than a single digit ?

Comment: @solinvictus: I'd say it's an issue with the specification, but you can just iterate in reverse: `for i, arg in reversed(enumerate(args)):`. That way the larger numbers are replaced first and won't be confused by the smaller numbers.

Comment: @Claudiu : cool that'd work thanks for all the help , Wish you well .

Comment: Found myself in similar situation, thought of updating with the code I used. `re.sub(r'\%([0-9])',lambda m:'{' + m.group(1) + '}', inputstring).format(*args)`. Don't forget to do `import re`.